# Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source... in vue-pdf

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-pdf

I'm using vue-pdf for pdf-viewer.
but I have got this error.

this is my code

```
<template>
...
<pdf :src="pdfUrl" />
...
</template>

<script>
...
import pdf from 'vue-pdf'

export default {
  ...
  components: {
   ...,
   pdf
  }
  data() {
    return ({
      pdfUrl: "...",
      ....
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

this is error image [image]

please help me.

Comment: You don't need SO's help: the error literally tells you what's wrong, and google will be more than happy to help you: make your server send CSP headers to allow `eval`. Something you _never_ want to allow, but go for it if you _really_ need this functionality client-side rather than building PDFs server side and having users download those, instead.

Comment: Could you explain more details? what's the solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong. Please help me.

Comment: So google for your error: CSP is a thing you need to know about when you're hosting content on any server on the modern internet, read up on it. Start on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your help. but I don't know how to use it in my case.
Please explain.

Comment: No: you can read, so you can read up on what `unsafe-eval` means for script CSP. You don't need SO's help here: there are plenty of resources that explain this on the internet already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235201/discussion-between-boris-and-mike-pomax-kamermans).

Comment: @Boris The recommendation with unsafe-eval makes sense but it can indicate underlying problem. Make sure you use the latest vue-pdf version. The problem is specific to pdfjs lib and it seems it has been solved some time ago.

Comment: I have installed latest vue-pdf version `4.3.0`.

Comment: but can't solve this problem.